# Navigation to other GWT module with Spring Security after successfull login

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I have a GWT application consisting from two modules: "Application" for main functionality and "Login" for login/forgot password/register new user functionality.

I'm using Spring Security to redirect user to Application.html on successfull login:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Application.html**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/Login.html" default-target-url="/MainApplication.html" 
        always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/Login.html?failed=true"/>
</security:http>
```

After successfull user authentication via Login.html, Application.html module is loaded and corresponding requests are performed to server, but browser content stays the same and URL in address bar is still "Login.html"!

So, question is: why redirect doesn't occur?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are intercepting Application.html via the SpringSecurityFilter and the target URL is specified as MainApplication.html . In the mainApplication.html , try to put this

```
      <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=Application.html">
```

so that it move you back to Application.html . You could do some authorizations here if you need .Also  check if DelegatingFilterProxy is set properly in your web.xml .

my configurations are as follows . I use a GWT app

in my jsp

```
<form name="login" action="<c:url value="j_spring_security_check"/>" method="POST">
```

in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in my welcome.jsp

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=gRoles%>">      
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;  url=demoApp/demoApp.jsp">
</sec:authorize>
```

spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?error=Access%20Denied">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/demoApp/**" access="${app.roles}" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" 
                always-use-default-target="true" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>   
    <anonymous/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I've checked spring security in web.xml - it's same as yours and seems to be correct.
I've added <meta> tag as you suggested and got infinite loop - Application.html sends redirect to Login.html, it sends redirect back to Application.html and so on. 
It behaves exactly the same way as if spring security rejected access somewhere during loading "Application" module, but I am _definetly_ sure that everything is fine with authorization - I've reduced security config to enable anonymous access to all resources and turned on DEBUG logging for it.

Comment: @Valrog Please log your answer if you get a solution to this .